# How do I fix the error code U1000 in Visual Studio 2019 NMAKE?

Tags: makefile, nmake, devkitpro

I recently decided to get into Nintendo DS programming, so downloaded devkitPro, which uses makefiles. When attempting to build a copy of a "hello_world" project, I get this error:

```
U1000   syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation
```

This line is the culprit:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(DEVKITARM)),)
```

I copied the makefile from this example in devkitPro: `..\devkitPro\examples\nds\hello_world\Makefile`
Having never used NMAKE or makefiles before, and not seeing any missing ')'s, I have no idea how to fix this issue, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem you're having is that this makefile is a GNU make makefile not an nmake makefile.  It cannot be used with `nmake` which is a completely different implementation of make (actually nmake isn't more than superficially related to POSIX standard make).  You'll have to go find a version of GNU make for Windows if you want to use this makefile.  I have no idea whether "devkitPro" is intended for use on Windows; if not then this is just the beginning of your journey.